# AggregationStrategy warns on timeout all the time

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-3

Why does AggregationStrategy implementation always [log a warning](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/febefe7630c1db9400922ca1550372faa118e21a/core/camel-api/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/AggregationStrategy.java#L132) when it times out?  I do not see any exchange/data loss in the aggregation, when this happens.

[AggregateProcessor calls](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/febefe7630c1db9400922ca1550372faa118e21a/core/camel-base/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/aggregate/AggregateProcessor.java#L782) this timeout method when the completionTimeout requirement has been met. Any logging of that event could be debug or informational, but shouldn't rise to a warning.

```
2020-06-25 16:06:54.454  WARN 1 --- [eTimeoutChecker] o.e.s.e.a.ElasticBulkAggregationStrategy : Parallel processing timed out after 1000 millis for number -1. This task will be cancelled and will not be aggregated.
```

Here is the aggregate portion of my route.

```
    from (direct:...)
        ...
        .aggregate(constant(true)).id("aggregator"+id)
                .aggregationStrategyRef("elasticAggregationStrategy")
                .completionSize(aggregatorbatchSize)
                .completionTimeout(aggregatorbatchTimeout)
            .to("seda:aggregatedPayload")
        .end()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is harmless. There is open Jira [CAMEL-15244](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-15244) to remove/reduce severity of the message.

You have following options:

- Ignore the warning
- Submit PR - please add Jira comment before working on task
- Wait until someone resolves that

Comment: Thanks for confirming its harmless.  I've overridden the method in my local aggregation class to log at debug.